# All products (category and sub category products) count on category list page in magento

Tags: magento, collections

I want to show count for all the products under category and also sub categories.I can't use toolbar for that purpose.I know default magento toolbar have code but i want to use custom code to only get count.i try to get collection by calling block method `getTotalNum()` but didn't succeeded.Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you tell us the .phtml file you plan to put the code in for displaying the totals? Or are you planning to create a completely independent block?

Comment: @Malachy If you see my question title i mentioned that i want to display that count on category list page.

Answer (score 1):

In `list.phtml` you can try this code:

```
//get the current layer
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');

//get the current category
$currentCategory = $this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory();

//get the subcategories
$categoriesChildren = $currentCategory->getChildrenCategories(); //means get your children
$categoriesSiblings = $currentCategory->getParentCategory()->getChildrenCategories(); //means get your siblings
//(decide if you want to use siblings or children, here we use children)

//get the product collection for the current layer
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection'); 
$layer->prepareProductCollection($productCollection);

//count up
$productCollection->addCountToCategories($categoriesChildren); //note the function accepts a collection of categories and counts them all

//display
echo("<ol>".PHP_EOL);
foreach ($categoriesChildren as $key=>$_category){
  if($_category->getIsActive()){
    echo("<li>".PHP_EOL);
    echo("<a href=\"".$this->getCategoryUrl($_category)."\">".$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()));
    echo("(".$_category->getProductCount().")</a>".PHP_EOL);
    echo("</li>".PHP_EOL);
  }
}
echo("</ol>".PHP_EOL);
//done
```

I think you might want to customise it a little.